# How to loop different size of images in while clause in php

Tags: php

[image]

I just want to loop images from database like the upper image. How can I do this?

Comment: So you think you can do this with php without css?

Comment: of course no. i know i use css and maybe jquery but i just don't know the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution [Masonry Cascading grid layout library](https://masonry.desandro.com/#getting-started).

Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort of like a mason fitting stones in a wall. You’ve probably seen it in use all over the Internet.

You can go with this. Check the link above.
Hope this will help you. :)